# Github Pages not working for static website

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, github-pages

I have a static website [repository](https://github.com/develijahlee/pizza-legends) that is pure HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

When I run live server on VSCode, the site runs just fine

[image]

I setup github pages

[image]

But when I actually go to the site [link](https://develijahlee.github.io/pizza-legends/) I get a blank page.

Why am I getting a blank page when the site works fine in my localhost when using the VSCode live server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at your URLs.

In your development server, you are publishing at `/`

On Github Pages, you are publishing at `/pizza-legends/`

Your URL which starts `/Content/...` is going to `/Content/...` on your development server and find the file.

On Github Pages, it is going to `/Content/...` and **not** finding the file because it is at `/pizza-legends/Content/...`.

Fix your URLs.

---

NB: You had your developer tools open. You should have looked at the Network tab and seen all the `404 Not Found` errors.